# get_field is not returning value in advanced-custom-fields-pro

Tags: php, arrays, django, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I using advanced-custom-fields-pro in wordpress to allow wordpress user to type page id they wish to display in web, is there any way to get the data from wordpress user and in backend using wp_query and display the page with the data user entered in advanced-custom-fields-pro?

Please take note, i named the field as “feature” in plugin. For my case, ‘feature’ can be contain multiple value like 1,2,3,4 so i would like to get my ‘feature’ value in array, what can i do for this?

Currently, get_field didnt get value sucessfully.

```
$feature = get_field(‘feature’);

$the_query_featured = new WP_Query( array(
‘posts_per_page’ => 2,
‘posts_per_page’ => 2,
‘nopaging’ => false,
‘order’ => ‘DESC’, //’order’ => ‘ASC’,
‘orderby’ => ‘date’,
‘meta-key’ => $feature,
‘page_id’ => $feature,
‘post_type’ => ‘any’
));

<?php while ( $the_query_featured->have_posts() ) : $the_query_featured->the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: Where is `feature` field saved? in the user meta?

Comment: its saving the pages id like 1240,1230,3456

Comment: in my case, i want to display pages according what feature field saved